# JavaFX subclassed Button - How to make Label update work?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to have several JavaFX Buttons that update one Label in my Application with text. For testing purposes it's just Button Text.

What I did at first worked fine and looked like this:

```
String Text = "...";

public void kons() {
    System.out.println("Works...");
    System.out.println(Text);
    Tekst.setText(Text);

Button G4 = new Button("Spadantes");
        G4.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Text = G4.getText();
                kons();
            }
        });
```

Then I decided to stylize my buttons with CSS and because I wanted to have several groups of buttons stylized in different way I subclassed JavaFX Button class in this way:

```
public class Buttons extends Button {

    public Buttons(String text) {
        super(text);
        getStylesheets().clear();
        getStylesheets().add("./Buttons.css");
```

Which still worked. But now I want my event handler to be moved to Button subclass (to avoid copy-pasting exactly same code into each and every button of mine). What I did looks like this:

```
public class Buttons extends Button {

    public Buttons(String text) {
        super(text);
        getStylesheets().clear();
        getStylesheets().add("./Buttons.css");

        setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Main.Text = getText();
                Main.kons();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> Main is my extend Application class
>
> Tekst is my label.

And sadly it throws me exception about calling non-stathic method and variable from static context. From what I understand instances are static and definitions are non-static. I tried to change everything "in the way" to static but it gives me red wall of errors after clicking button (nothing in compilation process). I also tried to call instance of my Application somehow but I have no idea how (from what I understand extend Application class intantiates itself on it's own while starting program so there's no "name" by which I can call it's Label.

What I'm looking for is "quick and dirty solution" to be able to use subclassed buttons (or other sliders, text-fields, etc.) that can call a method that updates something "on screen".

[EDIT] I'm using newest Java there is of course. In case it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of subclassing, why not just write a utility method that creates the buttons for you? I would also not recommend making the `text` variable an instance variable: just reference the `Label` directly.

```
public class SomeClass {

    private Label tekst ;

    // ...

    private Button createButton(String buttonText) {
        Button button = new Button(buttonText);
        button.getStylesheets().add("Buttons.css") ; 
        button.setOnAction(e -> tekst.setText(buttonText));
        return button ;
    }
}
```

Then, from within the same class, when you need one of those buttons you just do

```
Button button = createButton("Text");
```

If you really want to subclass (which just seems unnecessary to me), you need to pass a reference to the label to the subclass:

```
public class LabelUpdatingButton extends Button {

    public LabelUpdatingButton(String text, Label labelToUpdate) {
        super(text);
        getStylesheets().add("Buttons.css");
        setOnAction(e -> labelToUpdate.setText(getText()) );
    }
}
```

Then from your class that assembles the UI you can do

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label tekst = new Label();
        Button someButton = new LabelUpdatingButton("Button text", tekst);
        // etc...
    }
}
```

But again, creating a subclass that does nothing other than define a constructor that calls public API methods is redundant, imo.

Also, it's a bit unusual to create an entire stylesheet just for your buttons. Typically you would set a style class on the `Button`:

```
button.getStyleClass().add("my-button-class");
```

and then in the stylesheet you add to the `Scene` do

```
.my-button-class {
    /* styles for this type of button */
}
```

Comment: The middle sections of Your answer is what I'm looking for but my label is still defined in different class then my button subclass and Your code wont work because of this "static, non-static" thingy. My Application is one class (file) and my button sublass is another class (file). In the end it will be something game-like and I will have many subclassed entities spread around many class/files so I need to know how to change what's on display (buttons, labels, everything) from classes and subclasses outside...

Comment: But surely you are creating & using the buttons in the same class as the label? Just pass the reference to the label to the button subclass constructor. See update.

Comment: Depends on what You mean by "Creating and using". Event handler itself is defined in subclass file and in my main file there is only MY_SUBCLASS CHEWBACCA = new MY_SUBCLASS. That's all. The whole idea was to have everything written in subclass and only creating instance that does everything right out of the box.

Comment: How does my example not do that?

Comment: It actually worked like a charm. I had some syntax bug on my side (something else interacted with the part of code I presented here). Great thanks, You're the best :-) Would be even more awesome if I understood why doesn't it throw "static vs non-static" error now (we're still communicating the same 2 entities, this didn't change) but the most important thing is it works :-) EDIT: Care to add reference to the "e ->" syntax? I see it for the first time in my life...

Comment: Status vs non static is a very fundamental Java concept. You won't be able to get far if you don't understand it. I'm sure if you google something like "What does static mean in Java?" you will find many results.

Comment: I do understand static vs non-static issue in general. But by definition to deal with such thing I should either change everything that participates in my desired command-chain to static (which in case of JavaFX throws wall of red errors as I wrote in my question) or communicate only instance <> instance or definition <> definition. Didn't change such a thing and error disappeared with Your solution - this part I don't understand. Btw. I case You missed I edited last comment: do You have any reference to the "e ->" syntax You used? Never seen it and don't find it in uncle Google.

Comment: You say "From what I understand instances are static and definitions are non-static", which is a misunderstanding. (I'm not even really sure it means anything.) My code doesn't generate that error because I never try to dereference an instance variable (non-static) with a class name (static context). The `->` syntax is a [lambda expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Comment: [Here](https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/static-keyword-in-java/) is the best beginner explanation of "static" versus "instance" I can find in a quick search.